# Save user prefs on a site?

Tags: jquery, cookies, save

I'm building a wordpress site and I'd like to give readers the ability to change the layout and the fonts (some people prefer serifs/sans serifs for reading) and the text size.

Really prefer not to require user registration though, that'll just add another layer of complexity for what I'm doing at the moment, so database stuff is out.
Since the different settings are so basic I'd think there's something that could be done with cookies perhaps?

Though there's precious little information I can find on how to actually do it.

So, say I have a function that adds a class to an element, how would I save that for users after the page reloads?

Answer (score 0):

you can switch stylesheets with this plugin http://www.kelvinluck.com/2006/05/switch-stylesheets-with-jquery/ and when a user picks a theme, you can store the name of the theme in a cookie.http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp then retrieve the name when page reloads and load that stylesheet.

here is an example using `cookies`

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/f7mXV/

i am binding two event handlers to two buttons, and getting the cookie where the font is stored. And setting the font to the stored cookie.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#button1").click(function () {
         setFont('serif')
     });
     $("#button2").click(function () {
         setFont('sans-serif')
     });

     var font = getCookie("username");
     $("body").css("font-family", font);
 });
```

event handlers call this function to set the cookie with selected font and change the current font.

```
 function setFont(font) {
     setCookie("username", font, 365);
     $("body").css("font-family", font);
 }
```

Comment: I think swapping an entire stylesheet is a bit extreme when all I need to do is change add one class to a parent container then write a few new styles based on that.

Comment: i don't think its extreme at all. it gives you the opportunity to have different kind of themes contained in their own css sheet.it would be alot easier to manage, expand on to.

Comment: @andy but after all, if you just want to change the font, then you can just save that font name in a cookie as well. and then set the font on page load as `$("body").css("font-family",yourfont);` yourfont would be the font you retrieved from cookie.

Comment: @andy i added an example. i used the js_cookies from w3schools. i hope it helps you